# How to implement map of dynamic indices in dart (or of different execution)

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, date, maps

I am working on an **app in flutter** but I don't think the solution to this problem is only *for* dart but *all the similar languages (python, js, even java, etc.)*, so don't feel frightened to answer if you don't know "dart".

What I am trying to do:

- `Map<date, something>`

  -> I want to have indexed dates so that I could:

```js
mymap[date0] -> something0
```

and (most importantly)

```js
mymap.of(index0) -> date0, something0
```

Problem: **I want to have existing gaps so that there don't have to be entries for every date** between for example 14th March and 10th May.

```js
mymap = {
 index 0: date 14.3.2023: something0,
 index 56: date 10.5.2023: something56
}
```

For that to work as I intend, there is a need for these features:

- If there is an existing entry `date0` and a **new date is added** that comes before `date0`:

  -> **every other index needs to increase** by the difference between `date0new` and `date0old`

```js
mymap.add(date 12.3.2023, somethingNew)
-> {
 index 0: date 12.3.2023: somethingNew,
 index 2: date 14.3.2023: something0,
 index 58: date 10.5.2023: something56
}
```

Any solution can even include two maps, pointer, lists or anything that isn't too inefficient because I could work around this if I didn't want my code to work efficient.

Comment: that's how a map works.  What problems have you had?

Comment: A map seems to be an inappropriate data structure. As long as index has a reasonable upper bound, use a `List<Thing?>` where `Thing` is a class holding the date and the something. Now you don't need to store index - it's the index into the list. Your `of` method is a simple lookup. Search by date is trickier: could be an exhaustive search, or binary chop. Alternatively, since index can be calculated from (date - date of first entry) you could use a `SortedMap<Date, SomeThing>`. Lookup by date is easy. Lookup by index involves adding the index to the date of the first entry then look by date.

Comment: Can you provide more details about your requirements? *Why* do you need a numeric index?  Does lookup by index need to be O(1)?  If you simply need your `Map` to maintain entries in a sorted, chronological order, you can use Dart's `SplayTreeMap` with a `DateTime` key.